# Android X server and java applications

Tags: java, android, xserver

I am using android x server on my android phone. I export my server's display to my mobile using the

```
    export DISPLAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0.0
```

command. Now i can observe the display for X applications like 'xclock', 'xcalc' and i can even get display for 'gedit'; but when i try to run a java application(hello world dialog box) i get the following error.

```
     *** Error in `java': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0819b130 ***
```

i can see the dialog box on mobile but without the message 'hello world' also i cannot close the dialog box.
How can I make java applications or jar files run on X server?